# Sanitize (not remove) HTML input for breaking the document, but not other tags

Tags: php, html, sanitization, xss

Lets assume we have a user form that generates HTML input, and the following could be an example of what gets POSTed to PHP.

```
<p>Hello</p>
<p><strong>World</strong></p>
```

Now, these will show up later on via injected to the HTML output, into some DIV.

What I'd like to prevent is the following being entered in:

```
</div>
<p>Hello</p>
<p><strong>World</strong></p>
<div>
```

Or even something like:

```
</div>
<script> someScript(); </script>
<iframe src="http://www.example.com">......
<p>Hello</p>
<p><strong>World</strong></p>
<div>
```

How can I use PHP to determine that this input will not break the document, include bad iframes, or run scripts? The most importat part is I still want that information, I'm not throwing it out, but it needs to be included as harmless text of some sort.

Using alternative markup is not an option, it needs to be HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you need is [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Not only it outputs html according to standars but it cleans the posted code from xss vulnerabilities.

**Edit 1**: you should also [check the comparison](http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison) out , its interesting:)

**Edit 2**: you can also check out [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) 
but imo htmlpurifier is far better and much more customizable, when it comes to more complex things, like yours.

Comment: How do I configure this to not just remove text? I want to see the <script> tags in the code, just something done to them such that they won't run.

Comment: so you want random tags  like  <strong> or <p> to work, but <script> tags to just be visible?and  tags that break your html disappeared?

Comment: All content stays, but is simply put into a state that will not break the document by changing the DOM, adding iframes, or running scripts.

Comment: check my edit.with these 2 functions all content stays and output as text,its the fast and easy solution :P they can be a bit buggy though if you use non-latin languages

Comment: @Incognito, If you want to tidy up normal HTML (make sure tags match, etc), and change certain specified tags to plain text, you need HTML Purifier plus a custom injector. As I say in my answer, such an injector has already been written for `<a>` tags. It should be fairly easy to modify it for `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the broken tags but render them harmless, I'd suggest saving it twice. Save the unmodified post data into one database column, and the [Purified](http://htmlpurifier.org) into another. Display the Purified version usually, and the dangerous version only when you need to.

Somewhere on the HTML Purifier support forums there's an example of how to change `<a href="dangerous.url.or.javascript">text</a>` to `<span>text (dangerous.url.or.javascript)</span>`. This may be the sort of thing you're looking for when you say you want to keep the information, not throw it out.

HTML Purifier is highly customisable, and the author, Ambush Commander, is very helpful both on the HTML Purifier forum and here at StackOverflow.